# Gated check - in tfs

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, checkin

I have a large solution. I want the ability to do gated check in on one specific file. I.e if I do check in on this specific file (that file could impact on all the solution) all the solution will build (gated check in), but if I'll do check in on another file it will do regular check in, without build.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to configure this out of the box. You can have Gated checkin or not configured at the solution. It will trigger based on the scope of the path configured for source.

You could create an ISubscriber event in code that checks each checkin for the offending file and kicks off a build if it is detected.